# submitting popup div without refreshing the parent page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a parent page main.php which is already running using ajax. Now in this page with a click on an image I am opening a popup div using jquery.In the popup div  certain data are entered and I need to save the data in the database .
While doing this , I am using a button which submits the form, but because of  this the parent page is getting refreshed.
How to avoid this...

```
      /*main.php */

       <form id="popform">
       <input type="hidden" id="hdnsubmt">
      <div id="popup">
         <input type="text" id="text1"  name="text1" value=" ">
         <input type="button" value="submit" id="btnsubmit" onclick="submitform();">
      </div>
       </input>
     </form>

    <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#popup').hide();  

       $( "#image1" ).click(function() {
                  $('#popup').show(); //if image is clicked pop up appears
                         });
       });
       function submitform()
        {

           document.popform.submit();
         }


   </script>

     <?php 
          if (isset('hdnsubmit'))
          {
           // save the data into the database;
           }

      ?>
```

I need to just submit the pop-up div without refreshing the main page and I am already using ajax in the main page,so I need to avoid ajax in this case.. Please help..

Comment: There should be no reason that you cannot use ajax once again to submit the information - especially given that you wish to do so without refreshing the page

Comment: @RamRaider .. I wanted to do without ajax. but I think ajax will be better.

Comment: @RamRaider .. I finally used ajax and its working fine .. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

`<form id="popform" action="" method="POST">`

now get form content on the same page inside the `<?php  ?>`

example

```
<?php 

echo $name1=$_POST['name1'];

?>
```

Comment: this is again refreshing the main page.

Comment: @Gautham Jha.. Thank u so much..I did it with ajax method and its working

Comment: will only work with e.preventDefault in a .on('click') function^

Comment: @TT120 I already suggest to use ajax methods and that works fine too, so further commenting here and voting down is waste of time